# Returning complex numbers when it's supposed to be real numbers

Tags: equation-solving, complex

So I am trying to solve the following polynomial

```
1/48 Csc[θ]^2 Sec[θ]^2 (-6 - 3 b0 - 2 b1 + 
   12 b0 β + 6 b1 β - 24 b1 r^2 β - 
   6 b0 β^2 - 8 b1 β^3 + 
   4 r (3 + 2 b1 r^2 - 3 b0 β + 3 b1 β^2) Cos[θ] + 
   12 r (-1 + b0 β + b1 β^2) Cos[3 θ] + 
   6 Cos[4 θ] + 3 b0 Cos[4 θ] + 2 b1 Cos[4 θ] - 
   12 b0 β Cos[4 θ] - 6 b1 β Cos[4 θ] + 
   6 b0 β^2 Cos[4 θ] + 12 r Sin[θ] + 
   8 b1 r^3 Sin[θ] - 12 b0 r β Sin[θ] + 
   12 b1 r β^2 Sin[θ] + 12 b0 r^2 Sin[2 θ] - 
   24 β Sin[2 θ] + 12 b0 β^2 Sin[2 θ] + 
   8 b1 β^3 Sin[2 θ] + 12 r Sin[3 θ] - 
   12 b0 r β Sin[3 θ] - 
   12 b1 r β^2 Sin[3 θ])
```

and find it's roots when we have $\beta \in ]\frac{1}{2},1[$ and $\theta\in [ArcTan[\frac{2\beta-1}{\beta}],\frac{\pi}{4}]$ and $b_1$ and $b_0$ are the following

```
b0=
-((6 (3 - 10 β + 8 β^2 - 6 β^4 + 4 β^5))/(
 1 - 12 β + 42 β^2 - 64 β^3 + 54 β^4 - 
  24 β^5 + 4 β^6))
b1=
(24 (1 - 4 β + 6 β^2 - 5 β^3 + 2 β^4))/(1 - 
 12 β + 42 β^2 - 64 β^3 + 54 β^4 - 
 24 β^5 + 4 β^6)
```

Now I already have looked at the discriminant of this polynomial and I know that the roots are going to be real numbers but for some reason Mathematica returns me complex expressions. Can anyone help me out ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The presence of the complex constant `I` in an expression does not necessarily mean that the expression is complex. Some real expressions cannot be represented in explicitly real form (unless you allow [`Root`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) expressions). See [`Casus irreducibilis`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casus_irreducibilis). You might get more help if you include your code showing the variable for which you are solving.

Comment: Maybe you’re using the wrong solver, or using it in the wrong way...